# Create Sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a new sequence in PostgreSQL with the start value being the max of all available ids in all the tables using the following query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idschema.global_id_sequence INCREMENT 1 START (
  SELECT MAX(t.max_id) FROM 
  (
    (SELECT MAX(public.tbl1.id) max_id FROM public.tbl1) UNION
    (SELECT MAX(public.tbl2.id) max_id FROM public.tbl2) UNION
    (SELECT MAX(public.tbl3.id) max_id FROM public.tbl2) UNION
  ) t
);
```

This doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve the above in PostgreSQL using scalars or other means?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a query to provide the start value in CREATE SEQUENCE. You need to use `setval()` after you created the sequence:

```
create sequence idschema.global_id_sequence;
with global_max as (
  select max(max_id) as max_id
  from (
    SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM public.tbl1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM public.tbl2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(id) max_id FROM public.tbl3
  ) t
)
select setval('idschema.global_id_sequence', (select max_id from global_max));
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to do it in two parts:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT 1 START WITH 1;
SELECT setval('seq',  
 (SELECT max(val) FROM (
    SELECT max(id) AS val FROM t1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT max(id) AS val FROM t2) j));
```

Check [`setval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) at the documentation.